# Need help with artwork

Tags: phrases

Good day all,

Thank you for reading my request. I am making a painting and want to make it so that it makes sense to Japanese people. I am very interested in Japanese culture but would not really know how to pronounce a sentence. I hope there is some way to make it readable, without losing the design too much :)

The artwork is supposed to say: World Peace, which I found online to be 世界平和

I hope that is correct. I have added an image of what I am planning to make.  Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you in advance!

[image: WP]

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  The phrase is correct, but I think you might get some confusion from some of the lines since you have changed one or two in ways that look like different characters.  I don't know whether or not that is problematic in this case, so I deffer answering to someone who might know better.

Comment: Also, I do not know whether or not this question will be considered off-topic, but I would suggest you read up about what is considered on and off topic (link included).  You may want to consider editing your post to make it more on-topic. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As a minimum requirement, you should get rid of these vertical bits: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxMEj.png - they will impede comprehension.

Comment: For 平, did you change the orientation of the oblique strokes on purpose?

Comment: Also, I would consider writing the words in vertical columns, from top to bottom and then right to the left. I.e. starting at the right top corner, 世界平和 written clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

[image: WP]

How about this? This may be easier to read.

Comment: Getting rid of the extra lines helped readability, but this particular example requires more than just a moment to figure out which borders are part of the kanji and which aren't

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more proper to write it in columns?